# Israelly easy tho!

Tags: pattern, enigmatic-puzzle

(1) ENGLAND

(2) CUBA

(3) SINGAPORE

(4) HUNGARY

(5) CROATIA

(6) MALAYSIA

(?) ISRAEL

P.S It's not 7!

Options :

- 3
- 5
- 2
- 4
- 10

Hint 1

> Glycine is the only amino acid which is _________.

Comment: Any hint for this ?

Comment: @Arulkumar hint is in the title!! Also if you can provide an answer then i can give more hints!!

Comment: Any more hints? Seems like people here are stumped. Well, at least, me.

Comment: @WilliamNathanael alright i will make some changes and make it easier :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it's

> 2

because

> It's the count of horizontally symmetric letters (A, H, I, M, O, T, U, V, W, X, Y) in the name.

And the hint

> Glycine is achiral (symmetric).

Comment: Haha yeah!! you got that right!! I guess the hint made it too easy! But well done !!

Comment: Just curious, what was the original answer? Originally, the (2) clue was MALAYSIA, which does not fit with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot, but I think it's

> 5

Because:

> Israel is in an odd (5) position.

Also:

> Glycine has been found in outer space, but Alanine has not. If we replace Croatia with Israel, we get a pattern of two countries that have had citizens in space, then one who has not.

And lastly:

> Keeping with the Alanine/Glycine theme from the hint, you can synthesize with the names. enGland mAlaysia sinGapore = GAG; hunGary isrAel venezuelA = GAA, both being the codons for Glutamic Acid.

Comment: haha no!! but well tried!!! I'll give you a hint hint! Glycine is the only amino acid without a chiral carbon (alpha) atom ;)))