# Israelly an EASY puzzle tho!

Tags: pattern, enigmatic-puzzle

It's not a duplicate of [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53008/israelly-easy-tho), but I want to make another EASY pattern too.

> (1) Fiji
>   (2) China
>   (3) Cyprus
>   (4) Indonesia
>   (5) Kyrgyzstan
>   (6) United States
>   (?) Israel

P.S. It's not 7 again!

Bonus:

> Can anyone find any other country which has the number (1)? I can't!

Comment: Can you confirm Kyrgyzstan is (5)?

Comment: @Rubio Yeah, of course. If not, I'm interested to know what pattern do you get. (Australia is 5 too, if you don't like Kyrgyzstan)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Israel's number is:

> **4**.

The number associated with each country is ...

> ... the count of the letters A, E, S and Y plus one. This is hinted at by the word EASY that appears in the title and in the question in all caps.

Evidence:

> Fiji → 0 + 1
>  Chin**a** → 1 + 1
>  C**y**pru**s** → 2 + 1
>  Indon**es**i**a** → 3 + 1
>  K**y**rg**y**z**s**t**a**n → 4 + 1
>  Unit**e**d **S**t**a**t**es** → 5 + 1
>  I**s**r**ae**l → 3 + 1

Bonus:

> Countries that have the number 1 are countries whose name doesn't use any of A, E, S or Y. Besides Fiji, these are Burundi, Djibouti, Morocco and Togo.

Comment: Perfect! I can't find more (1) countries because I did it manually, lol. How do you find countries without certain letters?

Comment: When a question is about countries, I usually work from [this list](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries), which I've reformatted so that there's one country on each line. (I've also added Venezuela, which, oddly, is missing from the list.) Then I can run `grep -vi '[easy]'` on that file. (I do a lot of work with these Posix commands or with Python or with a simple C program, especially when looking for patterns.)

Comment: @MOehm the list is missing its entire V section, including Vietnam and Vanuatu

Comment: @Kruga: Oh, that's why. Good that at least the Vatican is filed under Holy See. (That looks like an edit slip-up; the V section was lost on the 21:22h edit on 18 April.)